# HTML5 frameworks for an enamoured Flex Developer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been working as a flex dev for many years, building really complex apps.  With all the recent hype, I'm interested in learning HTML5.

What I like about the Flex framework is it's a consistent, coherent, complete stack for building RIA's.  I like that it has a broad set of components out-of-the-box, and a framework for extending and building really complex, heavily customized & skinned components.

Are there similar frameworks out in the HTML5 space?

From the searching I've done, I see there's tonnes of useful `.js` scripts out there which provide nifty components, effects, etc.  However, I haven't been able to find a solid js framework with a mature and architected component library.

This worries me that in building a complex application, I may end up writing lots of plumbing code to wire together disparate components.

I know that HTML5 is still in it's infancy, so if there are promising frameworks that I should be keeping an eye on, I'd like to know about 'em.

My shopping list of ideal framework requirements would be as follows:

- Solid component architecture (including lifecycle events)
- Extensible
- Layout managers
- Browser agnostic
- Support for data binding
- Support for complex Skinning
- Abstraction of services layers & protocols (ie., SOAP / JSON / XML services are all a type of `IRemoteService`)

Along with the UI framework itself, what frameworks exist in the Javascript space for

- MVC architectures.  (Similar to `Parsley`, or `Maté` in the Flex world)
- Dependency Injection
- Unit testing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're a Flex dev, then might be be interested in checking out both the desktop and mobile versions of the Sencha Frameworks (my company): Ext JS for desktop apps and Sencha Touch for mobile/tablet apps.

Ext JS is focused on desktop web apps that can work all the way back to IE6, so there's not much room to be "HTML5"y although where we can we are (our new charting stuff uses Canvas, SVG or VML depending on the browser it finds itself on).

Sencha Touch is focused on Android, iOS, Blackberry and IE9(?) mobile browsers, so we get to use all the CSS3, localStorage,  etc. etc. that you can shake a stick at. If you're looking for a test case of what you can do when you start with an assumption of a modern browser then this is it.

Ext JS & Sencha Touch is components all the way down. The best overview of both components and layouts is [this article](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Ext_2_Overview) that was written for Ext JS 2, although the component and layout model hasn't changed much for Ext JS 3. Layouts are getting a rewrite for Ext JS 4 - which will have its first beta this month - to make them more like the CSS3 flexbox layout system.

Extensibility is the outgrowth of having a proper component model. Ext JS has a bunch of user extension components that can be mixed and matched. A good example of a professional after market component is [Ext Scheduler.](http://ext-scheduler.com/) There's also a [good tutorial on how to create components](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial%3aCreating_new_UI_controls).

Data binding: UI components are bound to stores, so multiple UI elements are updated with new data as it changes. You can read the [store API reference](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.Store) to get a sense of how it works.

Complex skinning - Sencha Touch has an [excellent theming system](http://www.sencha.com/blog/2010/12/17/an-introduction-to-theming-sencha-touch/) which is being ported to Ext JS 4 - but Ext JS 3 and 2 are a little more involved to theme due to IE6 compatibility requirements (you have to generate images)

Services layers are abstracted with [data proxy, which is extended for JSON, Http, XML etc](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.DataProxy).

Sencha Touch and Ext JS 4 have a (simple) MVC architecture. Ext JS 3 and below does not.

Here's [a good write-up on dependency injection in Ext JS](http://www.miamicoder.com/post/2010/03/22/ExtJS-Data-Store-Dependency-Injection.aspx) (but it should generalize to Touch)

For unit testing, we recommend Jasmine - which came out of Pivotal Labs.

Ext JS and Sencha Touch are pretty widely used - Ext JS mostly for corporate apps, but there are lots of big companies using it like Salesforce, Marketo and more for externally focused users. Sencha Touch has [a nice gallery of apps from our latest dev contest](http://www.sencha.com/contest/), you should check it out.

If you care about tooling, we also have a GUI drag and drop Designer and a CSS3 animation tool (the latter in developer preview)

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 Boilerplate may be interesting to you. http://html5boilerplate.com/

I'm not sure about JS frameworks for MVC or Dependency, but for unit testing Dojo's Harness (due to new user restrictions I can't post a second link, but it should be easy to find) is pretty powerful. I'd take a look at more of Dojo's stuff as they do some pretty cool work with JS

Comment: Agree as pure html5 and javascript (oh sorry that's not pure is it) it is also getting better as other people weigh in with contributions.

Answer (score 1):

Sproutcore is a javascript application framework.  It is fully MVC with a rich key-value observing/binding infrastructure that reduces the amount of plumbing code you need to write, if you use it correctly.  It supports most of your requirements:

"Solid component architecture (including lifecycle events)" -- every view has a bunch of lifecycle events.

"Extensible" -- Sproutcore supports mixins, and has its own 'convert prototypal inheritance' to classical inheritance stuff so you feel like you are creating classes in JS.

"Layout managers" -- You lay out your own views, where they are, how big they are.  There are SplitViews which you can resize, and nest, but this might be one area where SC does not meet your requirements (although you can easily implement view resizing via observing)

"Browser agnostic" -- it is pretty browser agnostic, like any other JS framework will be.

"Support for data binding" -- very extensive binding infrastructure.  If you bind a view field to a model field, it will update when the model is changed.

"Support for complex Skinning" -- skinned via css like any other web app if you don't like the default theme.

"Unit testing" -- SC comes with a qunit test harness in place.  When you use the SC command line tool to create a class (be it an M, a V, or a C) the tool creates a test stub for you.

'HTML5' -- sort of a nebulous concept to start.  SC definitely supports generating an html5 app manifest in the build tools.  There are frameworks available for writing to browser local storage.  I think more html5 capabilities will come online in the near future.

The NPR app on chrome app store and this [sudoku](http://sudoku.strobeapp.com/) app are both SC apps.

Comment: could you expand on your comment "...reduces the amount of plumbing code you need to write, _if you use it correctly_?" Maybe a link on what "used correctly" looks like?

Comment: @datico, I wish that was documented.  The best way to learn about it is to look at some open source apps, like OtherInbox (available on github)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might like the [Sencha Framework](http://www.sencha.com/) which complies with some of the things you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same boat as you.
All the js frameworks I found require a lot of CSS to make them half as good as native flex. 
Most of the newer js frameworks give up on older browsers.

Funding and cool demos may make meteor the long term js framework winner.

I like the simplicity of angularJs

here's a good comparison of some popular ones

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/08/01/rich-javascript-applications-the-seven-frameworks-throne-of-js-2012/

Comment: I've recently embraced AngularJS too.  So far, I'm really enjoying the process.